# Как запустить отдельного слушателя для очереди?

Tags: php, laravel

Добрый день. У меня есть 2 типа очереди, одна отправляет письма, другая пуш уведомления. В качестве драйвера использую базу данных.

```
$job = (new SendReminderEmail($user))->onQueue('emails');
$this->dispatch($job);
```

Для обработки очереди использую команду:

`php artisan queue:work database--daemon --sleep=3 --tries=3`

Как мне создать отдельного обработчика для email и для пушей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
php artisan queue:work database --queue=push
php artisan queue:work database --queue=email
```